# Getting 1 image to appear instead of 2

Tags: html, css, background-image

How would I be able to implement that?

Half an image on each side

Where 1 image fills both left and right panels.

I want one image to show as 1 whole image, then the transition effect to split it into 2 images.

code: https://jsfiddle.net/kqLpv21h/

```
.panel-left,
.paneldoor-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 8s;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);
}

.panel-right {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  left: -50%;
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  left: 100%;
}

  <div class="panel-left"> </div>
     <div class="panel-right"> </div>
```

Currently the image fills in both the left and right side.

I want only one image to appear, that fills in both sides.

[image]

Comment: A _proper_ [mre] of your issue belongs directly inside your question, do not just show a snippet of CSS, and the rest on an external platform.

Comment: CSS without the HTML it is supposed to apply to, is still rather unclear. (Please note that for the next time you ask, at least.) You will have to work with the background-position here, and you will have to specify the background size a different way - `cover` won’t do you any good here, because that it applied based on the size of the actual elements.

Comment: Would probably be easier, if you wrapped both those panels into an additional element, and applied the background to that then.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: I tried that here and now no image is appearing. Just a blank screen. https://jsfiddle.net/aqu5powz/    <div class="image"> 
         <div class="panel-left"> </div>
         <div class="panel-right"> </div>
         </div>

Comment: I just tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: I did that, it's not working: https://jsfiddle.net/gf0eywbo/ .image {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
}

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: I want one image to show as 1 whole image, then the transition effect to split it into 2 images. Is that better?

Comment: What I would be doing is, Splitting one background image into two divs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234669/discussion-between-michelle-smith-and-cbroe).

Comment: I still wasn't able to figure out how to do it. Can you show me please.

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Comment: Can this code be improved? https://jsfiddle.net/80ubxotj/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 8s;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
- background-size: 100%;
+ background-size: 100vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);
+ background-position: left;
}

.panel-right {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);
+ background-position: right;
}
```

This will make the Image seem like one. You might have to adjust some tiny things to fit your needs, but that's generally it.
[image]

Comment: Can this one be improved? https://jsfiddle.net/80ubxotj/

Comment: looks good to me @MichelleSmith, just make sure that the video does not start playing when a user visits the site.

Comment: What do you mean? It starts playing for you right away?

Comment: Looking at the javascript in this different code: https://jsitor.com/8OeEw1Xoj / Would you know how to disable it from auto playing in the code where you said it starts playing? This one? https://jsfiddle.net/80ubxotj/